# Re rendering issue in React Native

Tags: react-native

My editing information screen has to modify lots of information, and I use functions to return the UI like this.
The point is **when the input has changed** (email input, phone input,...), the **whole screen will be re rendered**. (like the function to render the uploading avatar below ).
Any advices? I just want my app to re render the component that was modified.
Thank you anyway.

```
_renderUploadAvatar = () => {
   const { shadowContainer, avatarImage, editPictureIconStyle } = styles;
   const { avatarUri } = this.state;
   const touchableProps = {
      style: { alignSelf: 'center' }, disabled: !!avatarUri, onPress: () => this.onClick('upload_avatar')
   }
   const avatarProps = { source: avatarUri || Images.defaultUserAvatar, style: avatarImage }
   const iconProps = {
      name: 'editPicture', fill: Colors.white, width: sizeHeight * 5, height: sizeHeight * 5,
      viewStyle: editPictureIconStyle, onClick: () => this.onClick('upload_avatar'),
   }
   console.log("EditCustomerScreen -> _renderUploadAvatar -> return")
   return (
      <ShadowView style={[shadowContainer, { marginHorizontal: marginSize }]}>
         <TouchableOpacity {...touchableProps}>
            <ImageView {...avatarProps} />
            <SvgIcon {...iconProps} />
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <Text style={[Fonts.style('primary', toRgbA(Colors.primary, 0.5), 'base'), { textAlign: 'center', marginTop: marginSize }]}>{i18nText('information.avatar')}</Text>
      </ShadowView>
   )
}

return (
   <Fragment>
      <Layout {...layoutProps}>
         {this._renderUploadAvatar()}
         {this._renderUpdatePhoneNumbers()}
         {this._renderUpdateEmail()}
         {this._renderUpdateIdentification()}
         {this._renderLanguages()}
         {this._renderEducation()}
         {this._renderCustomerStatus()}
         {this._renderPayOff()}
      </Layout >
      {this._renderApplyButton()}
   </Fragment >
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a component for each one of your controls and views. Those components should extend from PureComponent or, in case you extend from Component, you have to implement shouldComponentUpdate.

Here you can read more about the PureComponents.
[PureComponents](https://medium.com/better-programming/when-to-use-react-purecomponent-723f85738be1)

Comment: Create component for each one takes a lot of code mapping state and props, is there no way for me to do like above?